# What does ^ mean when running make?

Tags: makefile

The [make a lisp docs](https://github.com/kanaka/mal/blob/master/process/guide.md#getting-started) contain the following instructions:

> This allows you to run tests against your implementation like this:
>
> ```
> make "test^quux^stepX"
> ```

I've never seen `^` used with make before. It's proving very difficult to search for information on this (Google ignores it and [Symbolhound hasn't found anything relevant](http://symbolhound.com/?q=makefile+%5E)).

What does `^` mean here? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GNU make, ^ has no particular meaning (except when used in the automatic variables `^`, `^D`, and `^F`). The [makefile](https://github.com/kanaka/mal/blob/master/Makefile) of the project you linked to seems to use it as a separator for variable substitution, but this has nothing to do with make itself.

Answer (score 0):

the ^ (Circumflex) seems to have to do with macro substitution. I could be wrong but this is all I could find for you.  Hope it helps.

http://www.cs.nccu.edu.tw/~lien/UNIX/Command/make.htm